# partition graph into sungraphs based on node's attribute NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, subgraph

I'm using Networkx to compute some measures of a graph such as diameter, clustering coefficient, etc. It's straight forward how to do this for graph as a whole. What I'm interested in is finding these measures between nodes that have same attribute(say color). I'm thinking if I could partition the graph into different sub graphs, where nodes in each sub graph are of the same color, then I could accomplish go ahead and measure diameter in this sub graph. So my question is: Is there a way to partition a graph into sub graphs which contain nodes of same color?

I would really appreciate any insight.

Comment: Filter the nodes then [`Graph.subgraph()`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html)?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Graph.subgraph(nodes)`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html)

## NetworkX 2.x+:

Demo

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3], color="red")
G.add_nodes_from([4, 5, 6])
G.nodes  # NodeView((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

# create generator
nodes = (
    node
    for node, data
    in G.nodes(data=True)
    if data.get("color") == "red"
)
subgraph = G.subgraph(nodes)
subgraph.nodes  # NodeView((1, 2, 3))
```

## older NetworkX's

Iterate over ([`Graph.iter_nodes()`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/networkx-1.11/networkx/classes/graph.py#L610-L640)) and filter the nodes based on your criteria. Pass that list to [`Graph.subgraph()`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/networkx-1.11/networkx/classes/graph.py#L1548-L1586) and it'll return a copy of those nodes and their internal edges.

For example:

```
G = nx.Graph()
# ... build or do whatever to the graph
nodes = (n for n, d in G.nodes_iter(data=True)) if d.get('color') == 'red')
subgraph = G.subgraph(nodes)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Following your guid I found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/mrwIDdlcA3M) to be helpful too.