# Create partition from an existing graph in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

in `networkx` I have a `Graph` object and I want to store a node attribute like `partition`, to generate a partition. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: `partition` will be a node attribute ? edge attribute ? graph attribute ?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [NetworkX doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html), you can set attribute to your node

> Graph.add_node(n, attr_dict=None, **attr)
>   Add a single node n and update node attributes.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *n (node)* – A node can be any hashable Python object except None.
>   *attr_dict* (dictionary, optional (default= no attributes)) – Dictionary of node  attributes. Key/value pairs will update existing
>   data associated with the node.
>   *attr* (keyword arguments, optional) – Set or change attributes using key=value.

Use keywords set/change node attributes:

```
G.add_node(1,size=10)
G.add_node(3,weight=0.4,UTM=('13S',382871,3972649))
```

You can then access your attribute like so :

```
print G.node[1]['size']
>>> 10
```

---

As suggested by @P-robot in comments :

> You can then follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653524/partition-graph-into-sungraphs-based-on-nodes-attribute-networkx) to partition the graph based
>   upon the attributes of interest.

Comment: You can then follow this approach to partition the graph based upon the attributes of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653524/partition-graph-into-sungraphs-based-on-nodes-attribute-networkx

Comment: `G[1]['size']` does not work, probably the correct way is `G.node[1]['size']`