# Having a directed graph in pyhton (networkx), is it possible to create a subgraph according to a specific condition on the node attributes?

Tags: python, networkx, subgraph, digraphs

I have a twitter data set that i want to analyze,after creating a directed graph(the nodes are twitter users, and edge from a to b means a follows b)
how i created the graph :

[image]

I want to make a sub graph that contains only male users and edges between them, and another one containing only female users and edges between them.
thank you.

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of just linking an image of it.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar problem, and I think there are two fitting stack answers:

[Select nodes and edges form networkx graph with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350222/select-nodes-and-edges-form-networkx-graph-with-attributes)

[partition graph into sungraphs based on node's attribute NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653524/partition-graph-into-sungraphs-based-on-nodes-attribute-networkx)

The preliminary requirement is that you add attributes to your nodes and edges according to what you need to use later

Not sure if this is satisfactory, but maybe it'll help a little.

PS. If you've already solved it, paste your solution here so others can see :)